# REQ: Repen What are the possible consequences for refusing to use personal phone for authentication?

Tags: discussion

Request to reopen: [What are the possible consequences for refusing to use personal phone for authentication?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184944/what-are-the-possible-consequences-for-refusing-to-use-personal-phone-for-authen)

This question is answerable, and is relevant to the workplace

Comment: You didn't vote to reopen it? Why not?

Comment: The problem with this question is it asks whether there is an alternative to using a personal phone for authentication at a hypothetical company and what would be the hypothetical consequences to hypothetically refusing to allow the company to put an app on your personal phone. The answers to that are all opinions based on how different answerers imagine the circumstances at this hypothetical company. Even fixed, it's probably a dupe of [Being asked to install corporate software on personal phone](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/125075/26699).

Answer (score 2):

Reopen a question that is not even answerable because the user failed to provide his location? Sorry, no!

How can you reasonably answer a question like that without even knowing what laws could possibly apply or what the local culture is? Depending on the location, it could be a fully normal practice, or a complete abomination and a big red sign for a company.